# What's the maximum exposure time an iPhone X can reach using manual controls?

Tags: iphone

Using a manual camera app like Halide an iPhone 6 is able to achieve a maximum of 1/2" exposure time, what's the longest an iPhone X can reach?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the correct information that  answers the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is dependent on the Third party app you are using and not the phone itself.

I have several apps that allow me to use shutter speeds from fractions of a second up to 60 seconds and even bulb ( as long as you want ). I have used these apps on my iPhone 6 and my new iPhone 8+.

I use [Procam 5](https://www.procamapp.com/) as my main app but i have others. It has a slow shutter mode. ( i am not affiliated with procam, just a user )

Do some research when you are choosing an app to see if you can  find out 
what the manual control options for each app.

---

EDIT: I asked the pro cam five support staff the question and here is there reply

> "*Hi , Thanks for getting in touch with us.
>   The longest exposure time supported by the iPhone X hardware is 1/4 sec. Longer exposure time are digitally simulated. 
>   Please don’t hesitate to contact us again with additional questions or feedback. 
>   Best*",

Comment: No, it depends in the phone (actually camera assembly) itself. Applications that offer a longer exposure time than the camera assembly supports fake it by taking multiple images and stacking them together in software (which might work for the OP, or might not).

Comment: Yes, I'm not interested in software manipulation but the actual hardware limitation

Comment: "The longest exposure time supported by the iPhone X hardware is 1/4 sec" meaning it hasn't changed since the iPhone 6s. Adobe Lightroom doesn't go further than 1/4 sec on my 6s. Will have a look at other apps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if these are the limits of the camera assembly, or the operating system, or the application I am using, but using Halide I can set the shutter speed between 1/3"-1/50k" on my iPhone X.